# Gradle Task Execution Failure org.gradle.api.GradleException: invalid distance too far back

Tags: corda

Experience gradle/kotlin help appreciated ...

I just forked and cloned master into a clean intellij project.  All test cases complete successfully but these 2.  I ran ./gradlew clean build and am getting the following build failures:

````
net.corda.gradle.jarfilter.JarFilterTimestampTest > classMethod FAILED
    org.gradle.testkit.runner.UnexpectedBuildFailure

net.corda.gradle.jarfilter.MetaFixTimestampTest > classMethod FAILED
org.gradle.testkit.runner.UnexpectedBuildFailure```
````

The test results report ...

**JarFilterTimestampTest**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jarFilter'.
> invalid distance too far back
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':jarFilter'.
...
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: invalid distance too far back
at net.corda.gradle.jarfilter.Utils.rethrowAsUncheckedException(Utils.kt:25)
...
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
at kotlin.io.ByteStreamsKt.copyTo(IOStreams.kt:101)
```

**MetaFixTimestampTest**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':metafix'.
> invalid code lengths set
...
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':metafix'.
...
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: invalid code lengths set at 
net.corda.gradle.jarfilter.Utils.rethrowAsUncheckedException(Utils.kt:25)
...
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set at
 kotlin.io.ByteStreamsKt.copyTo(IOStreams.kt:101)
```

Comment: Can you run `java -version` and post your Java version please?

Comment: Yes.  I am on java 1.8:  java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)

But, was talking with an associate that had a similar problem and we stumbled upon the slack channel comment to be on 1.8 (171) or better.  So pulling down the latest java 1.8 JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Joel After updating to java version "1.8.0_181" gradle is able to complete the build ...

Comment: @Joel Just to share, we use the IntelliJ IDE and after updating the JDK and reopening the Corda project within IntelliJ, a gradle build kicks off automatically. The build completed successfully. The project structure, JVM, modules, and facets all appear to have been recognized. But, the kotlin directories were not set as "source" folders. Thus, IntelliJ was not able to resolve a Navigation to a class like Node or AbstractNode. I needed to "Rebuild Project" from "Build" on the menu.